# Ignoring an error message from yum command [when package is already installed] - bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am sure those using centos must have encountered the following message

> Package 1: something already installed and latest version

I want to make my bash script ignore this message so the user doesn't see this.

Attempts 
I tried

```
yum -y -q install something
```

But it is still showing up .....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to redirect output to grep and filter the message:

```
yum -y -q install something 2>&1 | grep -v "already installed and latest version"
```

Or just completely redirect all messages to /dev/null:

```
yum -y -q install something >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Redirecting of STDERR is not required.